# using a session to show text for a specific group

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

This is a part of my session script:

```
$group='admin';

session_start();
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['username'], $_COOKIE['password']))
{
  $cnn = mysql_query('select password,id,group from users where username="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']).'"');
  $dn_cnn = mysql_fetch_array($cnn);
  if(sha1($dn_cnn['password'])==$_COOKIE['password'] and mysql_num_rows($cnn)>0)
  {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn_cnn['id'];
    $_SESSION['group'] = $dn_cnn['group'];
  }
}
?>
```

I want to show "blablabla" but only if you are in a group:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['group']) and $_SESSION['group']==$group)
{
?>
blablabla
 <?php 
 }
 ?>
```

In my table is a column named as "group". The group of this session is named as "admin" (that's why: `$group='admin';`) but it doesn't show the "blablabla".

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($row= mysql_fetch_array($cnn))) {
 var_dump($var_dump); 
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
 $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn_cnn['id'];
 $_SESSION['group'] = $dn_cnn['group'];
}else{
 echo mysql_errno($cnn) . ": " . mysql_error($cnn) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: yeah also print the result var_dump($dn_cnn);

Comment: you have to be able to print the result before proceeding further

Comment: sorry I dont exaclty understand how I should do that?

Comment: maybe your cookie is not set , I dont know but add an else statement